# What are the default user accounts created by Ubuntu?

Tags: users, user-management, accounts, passwd

Knowing this would be very helpful for detecting suspicious user accounts as early as possible.

Comment: Given [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/857235/158442) in your other question, this question is no longer necessary, IMO.

Comment: @muru Though in essence you are right, I think that the question as stated here will more often be searched. I therefore think it should be flagged as a duplicate, so it does not get deleted (If I am correct on this assumption).

Comment: @muru OK I pointed this problem to that one. But I agree with Bruni that people are more likely to come to this question when they search about default user accounts so I left it as a duplicate instead of deleting it.