# Trusting non human users

Tags: permissions, users, passwd-file, shadow

When looking into `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` I found many non human users. I read a bit about it and know what they do (as a group, though specifically I see many I have no clue about). All of them (excluding root (locked pwd) and my human user account) have never established passwords (*'s).

Are there any tests or things I can or should do to ensure these are not leaks and we can trust them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check which package created a user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857224/how-to-check-which-package-created-a-user) (for the "leaks" part)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The existence of a user account in itself does not mean that user has any privileges, whether it's a "system" user or a regular user.  If you went ahead and created a new system account it would be able to do nothing - it would have the same privileges as `nobody` (indeed, most system accounts are created for the purpose of giving something as few privileges as possible).  Only someone with the privileges to do so (ie, superuser) can give another user privileges, by modifying ownership or permissions in the filesystem.

The onwership and permissions throughout a complete Linux installation are so complex that you can't describe exactly what they all should be in a single post.  If you suspect that your system has been compromised, you'd have to tailor your treatment based on exactly what the situation is.  If you have no reason to suspect this is the case then it would be impractical to audit everything in your system to ensure nothing has more permissions than it should.

Another note: system accounts generally don't have a password because you don't ever need to log in to them.  When an account lacks a password in `.passwd`, it doesn't mean you can log in with no password, it means you can't log in to that account at all.  The account can only be used when a privileged process spawns or switches itself to using that account.

Comment: I would add that, so far as I know, there is some difference between actually having an empty password field and having an invalid string there.

Comment: Behaviour of an empty field is not specified I think, but some software *may* interpret it as having no password required, while most will interpret it as a hash that doesn't match any password.  It's best to have '!' or '*' to explicitly lock the account against logging in with a password.

Comment: @thomasrutter, my information might not be current, but an empty password field *used* to mean no password-- so a very different thing from a locked account, obviously. A `!` or `*` is a safe lock-out because it is _not_ treated specially: No string hashes to these values, so password login is disabled (hashes are fixed-length, so there's really no string with this hash.)