# How do I check that my users and groups are correct?

Tags: permissions, password, users, administration, groups

I have many Ubuntu-powered devices around me.

As far I know `/etc/group`, `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` are created during installation, so they do not belong to any package:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/passwd
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/passwd
$ dpkg -S /etc/shadow
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/shadow
$ dpkg -S /etc/group
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/group
```

My question is in title - How to check that my users and groups are correct?
What if I misspelled or changed something by hand in such files?

Comment: Also see: [How to check which package created a user?](https://askubuntu.com/q/857224/158442)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Basic approach

I found very useful package for such operation. It is named [`base-passwd`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=base-passwd) and has the following description:

```
$ apt-cache show base-passwd   
Package: base-passwd  
...  
Description-en: Debian base system master password and group files  
 These are the canonical master copies of the user database files  
 (/etc/passwd and /etc/group), containing the Debian-allocated user and  
 group IDs. The update-passwd tool is provided to keep the system databases  
 synchronized with these master files.
```

Master files (in aforementioned terminology) are placed in:

- `/usr/share/base-passwd/group.master`
- `/usr/share/base-passwd/passwd.master`

The package contains only one binary `/usr/sbin/update-passwd`.
Its purpose is described in man-page ([`man update-passwd`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/update-passwd.8.html)):

> DESCRIPTION
>         `update-passwd` handles updates of `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group` on running Debian systems.  It compares the current files to master copies, distributed in the `base-passwd` package, and updates all entries in the global system range (that is, 0–99).

For the problem from the question we need to run:

```
sudo update-passwd --sanity-check --verbose
```

Also you can try to run the simulation (dry-run):

```
$ sudo update-passwd --sanity-check --verbose --dry-run
Reading passwd from /usr/share/base-passwd/passwd.master
Reading group from /usr/share/base-passwd/group.master
Reading passwd from /etc/passwd
Reading shadow from /etc/shadow
Reading group from /etc/group
```

Running without arguments will safely update `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group` or quit quietly:

```
$ sudo update-passwd
$ sudo update-passwd --verbose
No changes needed
```

The utility covers 39 standard groups - *adm*, *audio*, *backup*, *bin*, *cdrom*, *daemon*, *dialout*, *dip*, *disk*, *fax*, *floppy*, *games*, *gnats*, *irc*, *kmem*, *list*, *lp*, *mail*, *man*, *news*, *nogroup*, *operator*, *plugdev*, *proxy*, *root*, *sasl*, *shadow*, *src*, *staff*, *sudo*, *sys*, *tape*, *tty*, *users*, *utmp*, *uucp*, *video*, *voice*, *www-data*.

One can read local documentation about standard groups in `/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.html` (or [online](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.html)).

## 2. Deeper approach

**Warning:** do not continue if unsure what you are doing or if you are newbie.

Start with

```
sudo update-passwd --verbose
```

and then if you have installed other software from repositories and then trashed your `/etc/passwd` and/or `/etc/group` you can try to reinstall all such packages with **the command** based on [@muru suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/q/857224/158442):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall \
$(grep -RlE '(getent|useradd|adduser|groupadd|addgroup|chrgp|chmod|gpasswd|usermod)' \
/var/lib/dpkg/info --include='*inst' | sed -r 's:.*/(.*)\.[-a-z]+inst:\1:')
```

### 2.1. Broken `/etc/group`

If you have removed entries from `/etc/group` you will face error messages as

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unknown group 'crontab' in statoverride file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

You need to remove corresponding lines from `/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride` and `/etc/passwd` then try again with **the command** above.

Other possible error message is

```
E: Internal Error, No file name for dbus:amd64
```

You can fix it by downloading the package manually:

```
apt-get download dbus
sudo dpkg -i dbus*.deb
```

and then try again with **the command** above.

If you have removed systemd-related groups *systemd-journal*, *systemd-timesync*, *systemd-network*, *systemd-resolve*, *systemd-bus-proxy* from */etc/group* then remove them from `/etc/passwd` and reinstall `systemd` package with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd
```

then try again with **the command** above

## 2.2. Broken `/etc/passwd`

If you have removed entries from `/etc/passwd` you will face error messages as

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unknown user 'hplip' in statoverride file
```

You need to remove corresponding line from `/var/lib/dpkg/statoverride` and then try again with **the command** above.