# Remove unnecessary users on single user machine

Tags: users, user-management, username, user-profile

I have these users setup on my single-user machine and I'd like to delete unnecessary ones to make the list shorter:

```
$ cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
root
daemon
bin
sys
sync
games
man
lp
mail
news
uucp
proxy
www-data
backup
list
irc
gnats
nobody
systemd-timesync
systemd-network
systemd-resolve
systemd-bus-proxy
syslog
_apt
messagebus
uuidd
lightdm
whoopsie
avahi-autoipd
avahi
dnsmasq
colord
speech-dispatcher
hplip
kernoops
pulse
rtkit
saned
usbmux
rick
vnstat
nvidia-persistenced
guest-atkb2q
guest-u4sf2i
guest-rmlbtg
guest-mz53vp
```

Off the top of my head I'm think I should delete users:

```
games
mail
news
uucp
proxy
www-data
backup
list
irc
gnats
systemd-timesync
systemd-network
whoopsie
avahi-autoipd
avahi
dnsmasq
speech-dispatcher
hplip
kernoops
rtkit
guest-atkb2q
guest-u4sf2i
guest-rmlbtg
guest-mz53vp
```

But before bricking my system I'm wondering?

- How to delete the files they own at the same time
- What apps created these users and how to remove them too
- Did I miss some users to delete
- Will I be deleting users I shouldn't

I appreciate Ubuntu Bloatware created some of these users and there are many many Ubuntu apps I don't use.

Comment: This is a Bad Idea. What do you expect to gain? Until you understand separation of privileges,  and  why they're there, don't do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check that my users and groups are correct?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1048928/how-do-i-check-that-my-users-and-groups-are-correct)